References for simplicial analogue of the loop space
For a space $X$, I am interested in the simplicial analogue of the iterated loop space $\Omega^n X$ and also the infinite loop space $\Omega^{\infty}X$.
After some google search, (please correct me if I'm wrong) it appears to me that the simplicial analogue of the loop space (in Topology) is the loop group defined in Kan's 1958 paper "A combinatorial definition of homotopy groups".
I would like to know some easy references for it - so far I've seen :

The book "Simplicial Homotopy Theory" by Goerss and Jardine
"Simplicial Homotopy Theory" by Curtis
Kan's 1958 paper

Basically, are there any other self-contained references for loop groups (or anything that is the simplicial analogue of loop spaces) that is somewhat easy for a beginner to understand?
Also, some authors write loop complexes (for instance in Curtis' paper) or, some even write $\Omega X$ (for example in Goerss and Jardine's book, and also in Weibel's "An introduction to homological algebra" book as well [Chapter 8.3]) which confuses me - how are they related to loop spaces?
Furthermore, I feel that there is a big gap in my knowledge - regarding Simplicial sets. So, I would like to ask what are some good references to read after reading "An elementary illustrated introduction to simplicial sets" by Friedman? [it was an amazing read]

It seems you already know some definitions. Why do you not think they are analogues of the topological loop space?

@ Zhen Lin : As per my understanding, to be an analogue of a loop space, we need to have $|\Omega X| \simeq \Omega |X|$ ($X$ is a simplicial set).

Who says it is not? The definition given in Chapter I of Goerss and Jardine certainly has this property. The loop space of a pointed space is characterised by a homotopy universal property.
